# Qemu linux guest disconnected randomly

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, mac, qemu, arm

I have a mac m1 with an arm processor and I want to use Linux sometimes.

For this I followed this [guide](https://theboreddev.com/run-ubuntu-on-mac-using-qemu/) and everything is working as expected and I have a working Linux guest. The only thing I added is vnc.

The only issue is that the internet connection in the guest is disconnected randomly after some times (sometimes is after 1 minute and sometime is after hours).
The vnc connection keep working but I can't ping 1.1.1.1 or even the host machine (using default route ip. in my case 10.0.2.2).

What causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same issue, found [this](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/3372) on github

Comment: If this solves your problem, please put the details in the question explaining *how* it solves it. Don't just put a link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/578163)